# Implement a carousel in uwp similar to an Iphone Home screen

Tags: win-universal-app, carousel, uwp-xaml

Am currently working on a uwp project which involves using a carousel that has some sort of grid of pictures that can be swiped by clicking some round navigation buttons. This is also similar to the carousel in Twitter bootstrap. To get a better picture of this, an example is shown below
[image]

Rather than different apps on display, different pictures from the user library would be shown.  I would like to dynamically display the first 100 pictures from the user's library. I have searched the internet for something similar to this, but the closest I can get is http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/08/23/A-CoverFlow-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the FlipView class? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242678

Or the CaouselPanel class?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh967950

and implemented them with a different data template (perhaps a styled gridview) instead of strictly images?

This is the flipview page from the windows dev center:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview

It should explain the basics of how the itemcontrol works.

Comment: Take a look at the proposal for an official UWP CarouselView control on the WinUI repo.  https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/771

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FlipView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview). I hope that is what you are looking for.